# MySql record insertion stopped at 181822 rows

Tags: php, mysql

I used the Following php code to Generate 8000000 Random Strings each with length of 25 Characters;

```
<?php
require('rsources/conn/config.php'); //Config File Contains the Connection Paramters
ini_set('max_execution_time', 3600);
?>
<html>
<body>
<head>
<title>Code Generator</title>
</head>
<?php
function generateRandomString($length = 25) {
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    }
    return $randomString;
}

    for ($i = 0; $i < 8000000; $i++) {
        $newcode = generateRandomString();
        $sql = "INSERT INTO ftbl_codes (sid, code, is_active, used_by) SELECT IFNULL(MAX(sid)+1,1), '" . $newcode . "', '1', '' FROM ftbl_codes;";
        //echo generateRandomString() . "<br />";
        $result = mysql_query($sql,$connection);
        if ($result){
            echo '<b><font style="color:yellow;background-color:Green;">' . $i . ' : Code Generation Succeeded</font></b> : ' . $newcode . "<br />";
        }else{
            echo '<b><font style="color:red;background-color:black;">' . $i . ' : Code Generation FAILED</font></b> : ' . $newcode . " " . mysql_error() . "<br />";
        }
    }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

It Should Generate the Codes to be inserted into the table;

```
CREATE TABLE `ftbl_codes` (
  `sid` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `code` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `is_active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `used_by` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I am using Xampp, Server version: 10.1.31-MariaDB.
The Insertion works fine untill the $i Reaches 181822. Can you Help me understand where the problem is.

Comment: What debugging have you already done? Is it _always_ exactly 181822?  Does the loop continue but just not insert additional rows?  Have you checked for errors?

Comment: Use `sid bigint(20) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY` and `INSERT INTO ftbl_codes (code, is_active, used_by) VALUES ($newcode , '1', '')`. This will improve the performance. If not enough - Use *mysqli* or *PDO* with a prepared statement and a transaction. If still not enough - use a *bulk insert* or `LOAD DATA INFILE ...`.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel ; Thanks for your prompt reply... Many thanks Sir, your notes worked like a charm. I'm on my way to the second million.
I've also added the $i counter to the $randomstring to insure no repetition in the outcome.
$randomString = $i . $randomString;

Comment: @PatrickQ ; Thanks for your prompt reply, Sir.